# Missing commands from command palette

Tags: sublimetext3

I've installed SublimeText 3 using following commands:

```
$ wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text
$ dpkg -l | grep sublime
ii  sublime-text                               3176                                         amd64        Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
```

My goal was to install `CMake` package for syntax highlighting but I've experienced weird behavior. Following [this tutorial](https://fritzone.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/how-to-install-syntax-highlighting-for-cmake-in-sublime-text-3/) I've installed `Package Control` package via pasting appropriate commands to console. But after I hit `ctrl+shift+p` the only available options I see in command palette is the names of currently opened files. There is no `Package Control` nor other commands. I've found that `Package Control: Install` is available via `Preferences > Package Control` menu, so I've installed `CMake` package this way. But Why I do not have any commands under command palette?

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost immediately after posting to SO I've found solution. The problem was with multiple keyboard layouts. When I typed `ctrl+shift` my keyboard layout was switched. I do not know why this affected ST command palette but it does. I've simply disabled `ctrl+shift` using gnome-tweaks as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language)

Comment: `Ctrl+P` opens the `Goto Anything` panel (which lists open files/files in the project) and `Ctrl+Shift+P` opens the command palette. It would seem the keyboard layout shift stopped the `shift` from being recognized, so Sublime thought you were using the other binding, or something along those lines.